# Jmeter isnt recording java /*.do website

Tags: jmeter

I need record requests from `http://localhost:8080/home.do`, but jmeter is recording nothing. When i browse internet like google.com, etc. jmeter is recording properly.
I tryed set "URL Patterns to Include" to all but without luck. I tryed even leave it empty,but still no recording with my test pages. The sites is made by java, I only testing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check your proxy settings in your browser, cuz it's probably set to bypass proxy for localhost addresses. You should remove check from that setting and all requests are going to go through your jMeter proxy server.